# Scrapy Authenticated Spider gets Internal Server Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, authentication, scrapy, internal-server-error

I was trying to make an authenticated spider. I have referred almost every post here related to Scrapy authenticated spider, I couldn't find any answer for my issue. I have used the following code:

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import  Selector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
import  logging
from PWC.items import PwcItem


class PwcmoneySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "PWCMoney"
    allowed_domains = ["pwcmoneytree.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://www.pwcmoneytree.com/SingleEntry/singleComp?compName=Addicaid',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        return [scrapy.FormRequest("https://www.pwcmoneytree.com/Account/Login",
                                   formdata={'UserName': 'user', 'Password': 'pswd'},
                                   callback=self.after_login)]

    def after_login(self, response):
      if "authentication failed" in response.body:
        self.log("Login failed", level=logging.ERROR)
        return
    # We've successfully authenticated, let's have some fun!
    print("Login Successful!!")
    return Request(url="https://www.pwcmoneytree.com/SingleEntry/singleComp?compName=Addicaid",
               callback=self.parse_tastypage)


    def parse_tastypage(self, response):
      for sel in response.xpath('//div[@id="MainDivParallel"]'):
                                      item = PwcItem()
                                      item['name'] = sel.xpath('div[@id="CompDiv"]/h2/text()').extract()
                                      item['location'] = sel.xpath('div[@id="CompDiv"]/div[@id="infoPane"]/div[@class="infoSlot"]/div/a/text()').extract()
                                      item['region'] = sel.xpath('div[@id="CompDiv"]/div[@id="infoPane"]/div[@id="contactInfoDiv"]/div[1]/a[2]/text()').extract()
                                      yield item
```

And I got the following output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Python27\PWC>scrapy crawl PWCMoney -o test.csv
2016-04-29 11:37:35 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: PWC)
2016-04-29 11:37:35 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-04-29 11:37:35 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'PW
C.spiders', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['PWC.spiders'], 'FEED_URI':
 'test.csv', 'BOT_NAME': 'PWC'}
2016-04-29 11:37:35 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, FeedExporter
, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-04-29 11:37:36 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddl
eware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultH
eadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMidd
leware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-04-29 11:37:36 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddlewa
re, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-04-29 11:37:36 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2016-04-29 11:37:36 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-04-29 11:37:36 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 i
tems (at 0 items/min)
2016-04-29 11:37:36 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-04-29 11:37:37 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <POST https://www.pwcmoneytree.com/
Account/Login> (failed 1 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2016-04-29 11:37:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <POST https://www.pwcmoneytree.com/
Account/Login> (failed 2 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2016-04-29 11:37:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <POST https://www.pwcmoneyt
ree.com/Account/Login> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2016-04-29 11:37:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (500) <POST https://www.pwcmoneytree
.com/Account/Login> (referer: None)
2016-04-29 11:37:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <500 https://www.pwcmoneyt
ree.com/Account/Login>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2016-04-29 11:37:38 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-04-29 11:37:38 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 954,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 30177,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/500': 3,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 29, 6, 7, 38, 674000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 6,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 29, 6, 7, 36, 193000)}
2016-04-29 11:37:38 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Since I am new to python and Scrapy, I can't seem to understand the error, I hope someone here could help me.

So, I modified the code like this taking [Rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1901546/rejected)'s advice, showing only the modified part:

```
allowed_domains = ["pwcmoneytree.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://www.pwcmoneytree.com/Account/Login',
    )

    def start_requests(self):
        return [scrapy.FormRequest.from_response("https://www.pwcmoneytree.com/Account/Login",
                                   formdata={'UserName': 'user', 'Password': 'pswd'},
                                   callback=self.logged_in)]
```

And got the following error:

```
C:\Python27\PWC>scrapy crawl PWCMoney -o test.csv
2016-04-30 11:04:47 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: PWC)
2016-04-30 11:04:47 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-04-30 11:04:47 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'PW
C.spiders', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['PWC.spiders'], 'FEED_URI':
 'test.csv', 'BOT_NAME': 'PWC'}
2016-04-30 11:04:50 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, FeedExporter
, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-04-30 11:04:54 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddl
eware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultH
eadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMidd
leware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-04-30 11:04:54 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddlewa
re, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-04-30 11:04:54 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2016-04-30 11:04:54 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_comm
and
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 57, in run

    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 153, in crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1274, in
unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1128, in
_inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 72, in crawl
    start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
  File "C:\Python27\PWC\PWC\spiders\PWCMoney.py", line 16, in start_requests
    callback=self.logged_in)]
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 36, in
from_response
    kwargs.setdefault('encoding', response.encoding)
exceptions.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'encoding'
2016-04-30 11:04:54 [twisted] CRITICAL:
```

Answer (score 1):

As seen in your error log, it's the POST request to `https://www.pwcmoneytree.com/Account/Login` that is giving you a 500 error.

I tried making the same POST request manually, using [POSTman](http://www.getpostman.com/). It gives the 500 error code and a HTML page containing this error message:

> The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

This is a feature many APIs and websites use to prevent CSRF attacks. If you still want to scrape the site, you would have to first visit the login form and get the proper cookie before logging in.

Comment: I will try this and let you know the result.

Comment: This may sound dumb, but, i couldnt find the cookies, could you help me?

Comment: If you do a HTTP GET to `https://www.pwcmoneytree.com/Account/Login`, one of the HTTP headers will be named "Cookie" and contain the cookie you need.

Answer (score 0):

You're making your crawler do work for no reason.  Your first request (initiated with `start_urls`) is being processed, and then the response is discarded.  There's very rarely a reason to do this (unless making the request itself is a requirement).

Instead, change your `start_urls` to "https://www.pwcmoneytree.com/Account/Login", and change `scrapy.FormRequest(...)` to `scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(...)`.  You'll also need to also change the provided URL to being the received response (and possibly identify the desired form).

This will save you a wasted request, fetch/pre-fill other verification tokens, and clean up your code.

**EDIT:**  Below is code you should be using. Note: You changed `self.after_login` to `self.logged_in`, so I left it as the newer change.

```
...
allowed_domains = ["pwcmoneytree.com"]
start_urls = (
    'https://www.pwcmoneytree.com/Account/Login',
)

def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,
                               formdata={'UserName': 'user', 'Password': 'pswd'},
                               callback=self.logged_in)
...
```

Comment: I have used the code sample from Scrapy Documentation and made very small modification such as website, credentials and item. Anyway, i will try to change it the way you mentioned let you know the results.

Comment: I couldnt post the result here because its too long, so, updated my question with details, please have a look.

Comment: You're overriding `start_requests` for no reason now.  You want to leave it as it was so that it makes a request out of the `start_urls` tuple.  You're also trying to use `.from_response` class method without a response (which defeats the purpose of `.from_response`).  See my edit for more info.

Comment: I had almost quit scrapy. Logged in back here today and saw your update. Tried it and got no result. Can you teach me scraping with scrapy?